# Como hacer Login en Firebase con Twitter usando KOTLIN

Tags: firebase, kotlin, twitter

He configurado toda la parte de developers.twitter, strings, gradle...

pero al momento de implementar el codigo necesario para hacer la autenticacion he probado mil formas y no funciona ninguna. Ya he mirado todos los tutoriales de youtube y foros
No necesito lineas de codigo aisladas, **necesitaria ver el codigo total** que hay que poner para que realmente funcione.
En la documentacion oficial solo hay codigo para java, y no funciona transformado a kotlin

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.